# Editing/Deleting Calendar Events without notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, http-delete

We have an Outlook365 integration, which posts events to calendars from an external system via the Graph V1.0 API.

In November, a little bug has snuck about 2,000 events into various peoples calendars over the coming 12 months. We have managed to produce a list of the 2,000 odd Outlook IDs, but we are now super-worried that if we pump in DELETE requests for them all, the attendees are going to get hundreds of e-mail/event notifications telling them "XYZ has been cancelled" or similar.

(this bug was detected when a user told us they had been getting occasional event invites at 4am, so we assume that manipulating events via the API does dispatch notifications/emails to the users)

Is this true, and/or is there anyway to delete the event from Outlook without a notification being dispatched? We do not admin the target calendar, but may be able to get in touch with such a person if it was possible to do this from the Outlook365 side. We were hoping there might just be a `silent` flag/attribute or otherwise we could put in our request?

As a side note, is there any limit to the frequency/volume we can pump at the Graph V1.0 API in any time frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported on Microsoft Graph right now.

It is available on the Exchange Web Services APIs using `SendCancellationsMode SendToNone`  enum https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.sendcancellationsmode?view=exchange-ews-api

I would really appreciate it if you could request this on Microsoft Graph Uservoice so we can have signal from our community the demand for this. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests

Comment: I can't find an existing idea on the uservoice that matches this, so I'll create a new one if necessary. Hopefully I'll get the wording right, as I'm not a Microsoft API expert (as you can tell!) and I'll link it up here once I've created it (might be a while as I am dead busy in the xmas build up). Cheers